# Two un-ordered list in parallel: HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get like this.

[image]

To achieve this, I have done as following, but it's not working:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <ul>
        <li>java</li>
        <li>android</li>
        <li>python</li>
        <li>HTML/CSS</li>
        <li>Git</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <ul>
        <li>-----------</li>
        <li>-----------</li>
        <li>--</li>
        <li>---------------</li>
        <li>----</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to achieve the first bar next to java, second bar next to android and so on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you considered using a definition list instead?

Comment: Or, since this is tabular information, a table.

Comment: would a `progress` element not be a better solution?

Comment: @Mauro I don't know about that. Thank you for the new term. :p I will check it out.

Comment: @Juhana that sounds much relevant on this case. Thank you

Comment: So can anyone show me the exact way to do this?

Comment: added a progress based solution as an answer

Comment: why don't you use a bit more "col-lg-*" attributes to solve this... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are showing the progress of those values (or at least equating skill to them in some way) a pregress element would be appropriate and it wouldnt require all the positioning css in other answers

```
<ul>
    <li>java     <progress max="100" value="80"></progress></li>
    <li>android  <progress max="100" value="50"></progress></li>
    <li>python   <progress max="100" value="40"></progress></li>
    <li>HTML/CSS <progress max="100" value="20"></progress></li>
    <li>Git      <progress max="100" value="90"></progress></li>
</ul>
```

And then something like this in you CSS
(change as appropriate for your design etc)

```
li{
    width:280px
}

progress{
    float:right;
    border:none;
}
```

here's a [jsfiddle to demonstrate](http://atmd83.jsbin.com/hiyaho/edit?html,css,output). 
(obviously it would need a bit more styling Re: colours and the width etc to fit your implementaion but you get the idea)

Comment: Exact thing I was looking. No complication, no downvotes. Just plain and simple. Thank you. Can't wait 3 more minutes to accept :-)

Comment: no problem, its also really easy to animate, so you can have the value populate on load

Comment: Can I customize the way progress bar looks?

Answer (score -1):

Add css as float:left, and display:block.

http://codepen.io/vaibhavsah/pen/eNKRqG

```
.col-lg-3{
  float:left;
  display:block;
}

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <ul>
        <li>java</li>
        <li>android</li>
        <li>python</li>
        <li>HTML/CSS</li>
        <li>Git</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <ul>
        <li>-----------</li>
        <li>-----------</li>
        <li>--</li>
        <li>---------------</li>
        <li>----</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```